# Hide content on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Take a look at [this site](http://www.delicatessen.no/grunerlokka). I am trying to make the main content scroll beneath the orange horizontal line, without appearing above it, and at the same time keeping the native browser scroller. With the latter iframe or layer overflow: auto; is out of the question. Also chopping images to put them on top would not work because of the scalable background.

Any ideas? Javascript needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another

```
<div id="header-bilde">
 <img src="/images/sized/bilder/bilde1-1200x962.jpg" width="1268" height="1016" alt="">
</div>
```

with style:

```
#header-bilde {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

between #venstre and #hoyre.

Give #delicatessen, #majorstuen and #venstre z-index:10;

Give #hoyre z-index: 8;

Then apply the same js manipulation that you do for #bakgrunnsbilde to the #header-bilde div.

Answer (score 0):

How about using z-order and putting the header above the rest of the page with position: fixed and top:0;

Comment: Ohh... Sorry, that might require you to duplicate the top part of the BG image. Didn't notice you wrote you didn't want to chop images.

Comment: There is no content of the header that would be able to hide anything.

Comment: You can cut the top part of the BG image and replicate it in the header. I think this will be "lighter" than any JS solution, and will also fall back better for non-JS enabled browsers.

Comment: Not an option, as the bg is js-scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Well changing the `z-index` of `#strek` to `1000` and of `#hoyre` to 100 makes the div scroll under the orange line

Comment: But it should not appear above the orange line.